# Searching on chat always returns no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-search

It seems that after [the datacenter migration to Denver](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/126135656099/data-center-failover-august-8-2015), I can't search anything on chat. Searches for any keyword return no results on all three chat servers, `chat.stackexchange.com`, `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`, and `chat.stackoverflow.com`.

Can someone look into this?

Comment: cross site dup of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302071/chat-search-is-broken

Comment: Tried checking for it elsewhere, didn't find that result. Might be better here because it's a network-wide issue.

Comment: Maybe it's not a bug but made on purpose to save resources. Hope I'm wrong of course. (there are more important things than chat search, but it is nice to have)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did assume Denver was a full mirror of NY so what kind of resources should be saved then?

Comment: @rene dunno, but search requires indexes and probably a whole server of its own - take away the server and you save a few bucks. (usually the team responds quickly on stuff like this, the lack of any hint of response led me to fear it's by design)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm getting search results on all three chat domains, so I'm going to mark this as resolved. There were search indexes which needed to be built in the Denver data center, and while they were building, search results would have turned up empty. We actually started the index build before the failover, but it was interrupted by switching SQL masters, so it may have taken a bit longer than we intended.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but there seems to be an issue with [Search in Help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302130/the-search-functionality-of-the-help-pages-isnt-working) as well. Not sure if this is related/connected to that bugreport.