# After the move to Denver Stacksnippets.net is offline

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, milehighops

After the move of all services to Denver it was [tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/630105840175988736) that there was some performance degradation. Initial reports showed that at least [chat search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263342/searching-on-chat-always-returns-no-results) seemded to be the victim of that.

I would like to add [Stacksnippets](http://stacksnippets.net/) to that list of reduced functionality.

```html
<h1>help!</h1>
```

If this is intended due to less resources available I'm Ok with that, I'll switch back to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

If this is an oversight, can you give that server some love?

Comment: Love won't be enough for the poor server, it needs some **juice**! Lots of electrons to run through its veins.

Comment: Love is almost free @ShadowWizard ...

Comment: Not anymore, we're long time after the 60's...

Comment: Please, don't take me down memory lane

Comment: hey are you sock of @Bart?! Only he is old enough to actually be in the 60's and remember it.... :-D

Comment: I don't know but I asked [him](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3806811#3806811)...

Comment: Related: [Searching on chat always returns no results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263342).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a bug.  We'll investigate.

Update: I see the problem. Working on it

Update: Fixed. Thank @nick-craver for doing the heavy lifting!

Comment: Just curious: don't you have alerts in place when major feature like that just stop working and/or whole service is offline? (i.e. you need to wait until someone spot this and report?)

Comment: In general, yes.  This service is missing alerts.  I've filed bugs to have them created.  Why that part of our launch checklist was skipped is something else we'll be investigating.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the love ... send some to Nick as well ... ;)

Comment: Glad to help!  Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  Next step: an alert that tells us if we are missing an alert! :)

Comment: Don't don't do the alert for missing alerts thing... This is the _only_ thing that a process is good for. That or additional checks.

Comment: Nope, still not working...

Answer (score 4):

Was going to write this as a comment, but I thought I'd make it a full-blown answer instead...

The issue still exists, but however it just seems to be a matter of the server certificate rather than the actual server availability itself:

[image]

when loading the Snippet as a full-page frame:

[image]

After clicking 'Advanced' and clicking 'Proceed', I can go back to the Snippet and see it perfectly.
On Chrome 44.0.2403.130 (Official Build) m (32-bit), Windows 10 Pro x64. System clock is synced, so it's almost certainly server-side.

*Edit*
As [discussed in the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3808314#3808314), it turns out that quite simply, the ***incorrect SSL certificate is installed*** on `stacksnippets.net`. An issue which is easily fixed.

Comment: https is not supported, unless this worked before then it is a regression.

Comment: @rene I haven't ever used a plugin to force HTTPS (such as HTTPS-Everywhere) and I've also cleared my cache. Seems to be Stack Exchange forcing the HTTPS, not my browser. Saying that, I just tried it on Edge and it worked perfectly fine first-time.

Comment: But in your dev console I see calls to https.... nobody is forcing you to ssl, you seem to be already there...

Comment: @rene AdblockPlus doesn't try to force HTTPS, does it? that's the only thing I can think of...

Comment: @rene right after first login, user arrives to the https version of the site. And as you see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263354/after-the-move-to-denver-stacksnippets-net-is-offline), in such case snippets are still borked. Not sure whether it worked before or not though.

Comment: @cybermonkey anyway, this better be posted as new bug, tagged with [tag:ssl] as well.

Comment: sure, ssl is not supported, Nick didn't bring the certificate with him from NY and now we are discussing a bug in a functionality (namely SSL)  that isn't supported anyway... ;)

Comment: @rene but we love to give the team some future work, don't we? ;)

Comment: Yep, we do... we keep those bugs coming...

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263383/stacksnippets-has-the-incorrect-ssl-certificate