# Stacksnippets has the incorrect SSL certificate :(

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stack-snippets

As [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263354/after-the-move-to-denver-stacksnippets-net-is-offline), was prompted to post it as a brand new question, so here it is :-).

Earlier today there was an issue with Stack Snippets, caused by the move to Denver. That issue was fixed, but however created/revealed a brand new issue; *the Stack Snippets' domain has the incorrect SSL certificate installed*, [as confirmed by rene here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3808312#3808312):

[image]

when loading the Snippet as a full-page frame:

[image]

After clicking 'Advanced' and clicking 'Proceed', I can go back to the Snippet and see it perfectly.
On Chrome 44.0.2403.130 (Official Build) m (32-bit), Windows 10 Pro x64.

This issue is confirmed by running an [SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=stacksnippets.net), where `stacksnippets.net` achieves a fairly absymal 'M' (aka, FAIL):

[image]

Should be easily fixed by generating and installing the correct SSL certificate. Mind, I don't force SSL and apparently some users have no issues with the current SSL certificate.

I acknowledge that SSL isn't *officially supported*, but if so, why is an HTTPS connection being attempted instead of a normal standard HTTP connection? I see no reason to use HTTPS on Stack Snippets; content on the domain contains no private info and stores no sensitive data.

And no, I don't force-HTTPS on Stack Exchange or any other Stack Exchange site:

[image]

Comment: HTTPS is being used on Stack Snippets because you are accessing Stack Overflow over HTTPS. If you access SO over HTTP, Stack Snippets will not use HTTPS. Not that it should affect this bug being fixed, they definitely had a valid certificate before.

Comment: @KevinBrown I *don't* access Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange over HTTPS though, that's the problem.

Comment: @cybermonkey That's odd, I dropped by to report the same problem, but turns out that for me accessing SO over HTTP actually does temporarily fix the issue. (And no connection related extensions or anything here either, not sure how I end up on `https` xD)

Comment: @DavidMulder I remember that I accessed the original post by the 'Hot Questions' sidebar, where I learnt of this error with Stack Snippets; perhaps clicking on the question via the Hot Questions sidebar made it go HTTPS?

Comment: confirmed; pinging someone with access to the keys...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It now has the right cert - an oversight in the DC swap; thanks.